# function button.is_pressed from gpiozero do not work

Tags: python, pi-2, gpiozero

Im working on a university project with raspberry and gpiozero.

I need to manage the button response to take diferent actions.

The problem is that de function button.is_pressed its always true (even if nobody press the button). I tryed to read again and again the oficial gpiozero documentation but its the same as i type on my script.

The only thing I can imagine is that for some reason the button have a minimum voltage that python interpreter as a True in the is_pressed function.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import random
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import LED
from gpiozero import Button

buttonRed = Button(13)
red       = LED(20)
while True:
    if buttonRed.is_pressed:
        sleep(.3)
        print('button pressed')
    else:
        print('nobody pressed')
```

this is the output:

> > > > %Run test1.py
> > > >             button pressed
> > > >             button pressed
> > > >             button pressed
> > > >             button pressed
> > > >             button pressed
> > > >             button pressed
> > > >             button pressed
> > > >             button pressed

Please if anybody have an idea of what is happening i would be glad to know about it.

Regards !!

Comment: Would it be possible to take a picture of the connections to your Raspberry Pi. And do you have a pull up or down resister? Please edit your original question and add these to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import random
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import LED
from gpiozero import Button

## I forgot put this in the befor script !!!
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

buttonRed    = Button(13) 
buttonGreen  = Button(6)
buttonBlue   = Button(5)
buttonYellow = Button(22)

red      = LED(20)
green    = LED(12)
blue     = LED(25)
yellow   = LED(24)

while True:
    inputValue1 = GPIO.input(13)
    if (inputValue == True):  <<----(if buttonRed.is_pressed:)
        print('button pressed')
        red.on()
        sleep(.3)
        red.off()
    else:
        print('nobody pressed')
```

And the red (are using gpio LED and the BCM pin numbered) and work perfectly.The  red led y have on my raspi conected to a protoboard start on and off as well i press boton.
Insted of that, the buttonRed.is_pressed do not work with the same pin numbered, so i fixed by using something more basic "inputValue1 = GPIO.input(13)", but i do not want used it. If a have imported gpiozero library its just for using all the functions !!!

Finally, i forgot to mention that i' ve worked with a raspberry PI 2 so the pins number are right.

Regards !!!

Comment: that is not using GPIOZero library . `GPIO.input(13)` is using the RPI.GPIO library. If you want to use GPIOZero `buttonRed.is_pressed` then you need to use BCM

Comment: obiusly it is not gpiozero library, I just using to demostrate that if I solve the button pressed problem, then using gpiozero library to manage the leds conected to a raspi, the library and the pin numbered worked perfect, because the script resolve the red = LED(20) and then do red.on() and red.off() and work fine, the led start brighting and then it turn off and all of this its using gpiozero library.

Comment: Please accept your answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

The pin number is NOT the physical board number but actually actually uses the BCM number (Broadcom). So if you want **pin 13** you can see below that is **BCM 27**, the [documentation](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#pin-numbering) says you can use GPIO number as pins but they do not work for me either. Image below is from https://pinout.xyz/

[image: image from https://pinout.xyz/]

```
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  <-this is not gpiozero library
import random
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import LED
from gpiozero import Button

buttonRed = Button(27)  #<-- 27 BCM is 13 on the Pi
red       = LED(20)
while True:
    if buttonRed.is_pressed:
        sleep(.3)
        print('button pressed')
    else:
        print('nobody pressed')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but. it do not work. It is not a pin problem. In the script a forgot put this: GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False), even so it do not work. I can use the same base script and insted of that use led.on and led.off and it work like a charm. example: